# 4 bits unsigned overflow

Tags: c

Is it guaranteed that this piece of code print always values from 0 to 15 on any platform?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct UI4{
    unsigned value: 4;
} ui4;

int main(void)
{
    ui4 u;

    u.value = 0;
    while (1) {
        printf("%u\n", u.value++);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, unsigned integer overflows are guaranteed to "wrap around" by the standard.

Comment: Note that the addition implicit in the program is a **signed** addition. If the `4` was a `31` the program would be undefined for an usual 32-bit compiler. See http://www.flux.utah.edu/listarchives/csmith-dev/msg00314.html

Comment: @PascalCuoq I read that arithmetic operations of which the one operand is an unsigned and the other is a signed integer are treated as *unsigned.* Isn't that true?

Comment: The sentence “If an int can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int” in C99's 6.3.1.1:2 is usually interpreted as meaning that `u.value` is promoted to `int` at the time of adding one to it, thus both operands `u.value` and `1` are signed.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Strange. To be precise, I read this in a document that also made references to the Standard and stating the exact opposite. I also have experience accidentally doing this kind of arithmetic and having gotten an unsigned value.

Comment: In http://ideone.com/D2hyu `ui*ui` is an unsigned int product, `si*si` is a signed int product, and `u.value*u.value` produces the same result as `si*si`. Note that the consequences of 6.3.1.1:2 change for `unsigned value:32`.

Answer (score 2):

I think theoretically on some really odd architecture could give a different result (a BCD based computer)? But maybe in that case it's not a compliant implementation.  Realistically you should get 4 bits as 0 to 15. But don't overflow on purpose I say.

Comment: As per the Standard, unsigned overflow **must** wrap around.